# How to change the number of default partitions of Flink DataSet?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-batch

Here is a requirement: the data set is too large, we need to partition the data, calculate a local result in each partition, and then merge. For example, if there are 1 million pieces of data divided into 100 partitions, each copy will have only about 10000 pieces of data. Since the number of partitions needs to be used for tuning, **the number of partitions is required to be variable**. In addition, **all data of a partition must be calculated in batches**, and cannot be calculated one by one.

Implementation is as follows:
After the partition phase, each piece of data will have a key to represent the partition to which it belongs. And now, the data is should look like this: `afterPartitionedData=[(0,data1),(0,data2)…(1,data3),(1,data4),…,(99,datan)]`。
Next, use Flink's `partitionCustom` and `mapPartition` operators.

```scala
  dataSet = env. fromCollection(afterPartitionedData)
  dataset
      .partitionCustom(new myPartitioner(),0)
      .mapPartition(new myMapPartitionFunction[(Int,String),Int]())
…
…
  class myPartitioner extends  Partitioner[Int]{
    override def partition(key: Int, numPartitions: Int) = {
      println("numPartitions="+numPartitions) // 6 , CPU number
      key // just return the partitionID
    }
  }
```

However, there reported an error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.getBufferBuilder(RecordWriter.java:226)
...
```

This seems to be because the default number of partitions of Flink `DataSet`is the number of CPUs, which is 6 on my computer, so it will be reported `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 6`.

So my question is：is there a way to change the number of partitions at will? I found this parameter at method `Partition (key: int, numpartitions: int)` in API [Partitioner](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/Partitioner.html), but did not know how to change it.

**Is there a way to change the number of `DataSet` partitons?**

Flink version is 1.6 and the test code  is:

```scala
object SimpleFlinkFromBlog {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val  env  =  ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val afterPartitionedData = new mutable.MutableList[(Int,  String)]
    afterPartitionedData.+=((0,  "0"))

    afterPartitionedData.+=((1,  "1"))

    afterPartitionedData.+=((2, "2"))
    afterPartitionedData.+=((2, "2"))

    afterPartitionedData.+=((3,  "3"))
    afterPartitionedData.+=((3,  "3"))
    afterPartitionedData.+=((3,  "3"))

    afterPartitionedData.+=((4,  "4"))

    afterPartitionedData.+=((5,  "5"))
    afterPartitionedData.+=((5,  "5"))
    afterPartitionedData.+=((5,  "5"))

    // Comment this line will not report an error.
    // java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 6
    afterPartitionedData.+=((6,  "will wrong"))

    val dataSet = env.fromCollection( afterPartitionedData )
    val localRes = dataSet
      .partitionCustom(new myPartitioner(),0)
      .mapPartition(new MapPartitionFunction[(Int,String),Int] {
        override def mapPartition(values: lang.Iterable[(Int, String)], out: Collector[Int]) = {
          var count = 0;
          values.forEach(new Consumer[(Int, String)] {
            override def accept(t: (Int, String)): Unit = {
              count=count+1;
              print("current count is " + count + "   tuple is " + t + "\n");
            }
          })
          out.collect(count)
        }
      })

    localRes.collect().foreach(println)
  }

  class myPartitioner extends  Partitioner[Int]{
    override def partition(key: Int, numPartitions: Int) = {
//      println("numPartitions="+numPartitions)
      key
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions is the parallelism, which you can set on the command line when you submit the job, or in flink-conf.yaml.